# В css-grid бургер-меню находится снизу, но с помощью position fixed. При нажатии на burger все прыгает

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```js
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  $(this).toggleClass('menu-btn_active');
  $('nav').toggleClass('menu-nav_active');
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', 'Arial';
}

body{
  font: 16px/1.4em 'PT Sans';
}

p,
ul{
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

ul{
  list-style: disc;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

a{
  /*color: #1D745A;*/
  color: #e0001b;
}

article{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

header{
  grid-area: header;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 100px;
}

h2{
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin: 0 0 .4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.grid{
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;

}

.menu-block{
  grid-area: menu-block;
}

main{
  grid-area: main;
}

footer{
  grid-area: footer;
}

nav{
  background-color: #2f82ba;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

nav a{
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus{
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background: #ccc;
}


footer{
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}





/* desktop  */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .grid{
    grid-template-rows: 100px 40px 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header header header"
      "menu-block menu-block menu-block"
      "main main main"
      "main main main"
      "main main main"
      "footer footer footer"
  }

  .menu-btn{
    display: none;
  }

  nav a{
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .menu-nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
}




/* mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .grid{

    grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 1fr 1fr 100px 40px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header"
      "main main"
      "main main"
      "main main"
      "footer footer"
      "menu-block  menu-block"


  }

  .menu-btn{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: #2f82ba;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
  }

  .menu-btn span,
  .menu-btn span::before,
  .menu-btn span::after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; margin-top: -1px;
    left: 50%; margin-left: -10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: white;

  }

  .menu-btn span::before,
  .menu-btn span::after{
    content: '';
    transition: 0.2s;
  }

  .menu-btn span::before{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }

  .menu-btn span::after{
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }

  .menu-btn_active span::before{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .menu-btn_active span::after{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .menu-btn_active span{
    height: 0;
  }

  .menu-block{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  nav{
    bottom: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    /* animation */
    transition: 0.2s;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }

  nav a{
    display: inline-block;

  }

  .menu-nav_active{
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <header><h1>header</h1></header>
  <div class="menu-block"> 
    <nav class="menu-nav">
      <a href="#">Главная</a>
      <a href="#">Оплатить</a>
      <a href="#">Информация</a>
      <a href="#">Помощь</a>
      <a href="#">О Нас</a>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn">
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <main>
    <article>
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit <a href="">amet</a>, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      Facilis, mollitia, dolor, possimus, corporis repellat vitae iure aspernatur at dignissimos ut optio ullam dolore est. 
      Mollitia, odio laudantium quidem saepe veniam.
      </p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h2>We want a shrubbery!</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus consequatur alias earum obcaecati soluta. Consequatur, minus ullam asperiores provident et explicabo quis eos magnam ad voluptatibus impedit assumenda iure culpa.</p>
      <ul> 
        <li>The nose?</li> 
        <li>Shh! Knights, I bid you welcome to your new home. Let us ride to Camelot!</li> 
        <li><a href="">Look, my liege!</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h2>Help, help, I'm being repressed!</h2> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, atque, nam reiciendis magnam reprehenderit hic ullam minus repudiandae id et consequatur neque inventore praesentium enim velit eveniet commodi fuga adipisci!</p>
    </article>

  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Я сделал грид-сетку под различные медиа-запросы.

Как опустить содержимое menu-block в самый низ так, чтобы при нажатии на burger, ничего не дергалось. Сейчас я опустил содержимое div.menu-block c помощью position: fixed (причем это свойство определенно только НЕ у самого div.menu-block, а у его содержимого). Кроме того, нужно чтобы при прокручивании в мобильной версии burger-меню и nav.menu-nav не пропадали из виду...

Попробуйте в сниппете сделать маленькое окно, прокрутить в самый низ и нажать раскрыть меню. Вы увидите, о чем я. Спасибо!

Comment: Сниппет сделай.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦, можно подробнее?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXu2O.png

Comment: @Qwertiy♦, не знал, что это "сниппет" называется...

Comment: Если сделать окно браузере маленьким, прокрутить вниз и нажать на burger, то все прыгает... footer вообще в середине где-то

Comment: Вроде кнопка внизу и стоит, не как на твоих скриншотах: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWdoA.png

Comment: Я вроде сделал, да, использовал position fixed, но что-то подсказывает, так неправильно. Когда нажимаю открыть меню, дергается все...

Comment: Еще footer в середине, поверх другого текста

Comment: Почему footer в середине вроде разобрался: у меня в grid-template-areas "main" написано 3 раза - написал 1 раз. И в grid-templates-rows вместо "1fr 1fr 1fr" написал "3fr". Footer встал как надо